# How to index some fields of an object

Tags: elasticsearch

I have to log a dynamic object, but I'm interested only to index some fields (not all), but when I configure this behaviour I can't search for those fields.

Here an example of what I'm doing with Elastic `6.x`:

```
curl --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/manuel-prova?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "properties": {
        "hello": {
          "type": "object",
          "enabled": false,
          "properties": {
            "my-api-key": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "check": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Then I insert the data:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/manuel-prova/log?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "hello": {
    "foo": "bar",
    "my-api-key": "QWERTY"
  },
  "check": true
}'
```

Finally, I tried to query:

```
curl --request POST 'http://localhost:9200/manuel-prova/_search?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "exists": { "field": "hello.my-api-key" } }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

This query doesn't work.

If I change to `{ "exists": { "field": "check" } }` for example, it works.

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `hello` `object` is defined with [`enabled: false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/enabled.html), which makes ES ignore the content of the field altogether, and hence, it is not searchable.

In order to fix that you need to remove `enabled: false`, like below, and it will work:

```
curl --request PUT 'http://localhost:9200/manuel-prova?pretty' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "mappings": {
    "log": {
      "dynamic": false,          <-- add this
      "properties": {
        "hello": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {        <-- remove enabled: false
            "my-api-key": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "check": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: But If I remove the `enabled` flag, every time I send an object with other fields, it will index those field cause the [dynamic mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/dynamic-field-mapping.html)

Comment: then just set [`dynamic` to false](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html), see my updated answer